# Uniform convergence and Continuous composition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

In a supplement to Rudin's "Principle of Mathematical Analysis" I have stumbled upon the following exercise:

> Let $m:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function between metric spaces and let $\{f_n\}_{n \in Z_+}$ be a sequence of complex-valued functions defined on $Y$. Find a counter-example to the following statement: if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $Y$ then $f_n \circ m$ converges uniformly to $f \circ m$.

**My attempt**

First of all, I have proved the following two facts:

- if $f_n$ converges locally uniformly to $f$ on $Y$ then $f_n \circ m$ converges locally uniformly to $f \circ m$;
- if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $Y$ then $f_n \circ m$ converges uniformly to $f \circ m$, provided $m$ be **uniformly continuous** on X.

Therefore, whatever the counterxample, $m$ must be defined on a non-compact metric space and $f_n \circ m$ converges locally uniformly to $f \circ m$ on $X$.

My main idea so far is that $m$ should somehow *increase the distance between consecutive functions in the sequence*, however I do not know how to do it.

**Edit**

After trying to prove the statement it seems to me that the exercise, as it is written, is asking something non-existent. Actually, the statement can also be made stronger by taking away the continuity of $m$ (which becomes necessary only when we want to prove the analogous statement for locally uniformly convergent functions).

In fact:
$$\forall n \in Z_+, \sup_X (|f_n \circ m - f \circ m|) \leq \sup_Y (|f_n  - f|)$$
hence, we can conclude immediately by the M-Test.

Let me know if this proof seems right.

---

As always, any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer.

Comment: Did you copy  the exercise correctly? As stated there is no counter-example. It is pretty obvious that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $Y$ then $f_n\circ m \to f\circ m$ uniformly on $X$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I checked now and I copied it correctly. It is also written that the statement becomes true if $m$ is uniformly continuous and not just continuous. However, now that you point it out, it may be just plain wrong.

Comment: An obvious example to consider would be $m : (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty) : x \mapsto \frac 1x$. In that case, it is possible for $f_n \to f$ uniformly, while $m\circ f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $m\circ f$. But of course I've flipped the composition. I suspect that may have been what was intended for this problem.